# Excel VBA SQL SUM of empty recordset not returning zero

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'd like to use a sub-query that returns the sum of a column, something like:

```
3 + SELECT SUM(field) FROM some-table WHERE some-criteria
```

When the criteria results in 0 records, the sub-query does not return 0, thus the whole query failes and returns nothing (a zero-length nothing).

When there are records all works well.

I tried `SUM(IIF(field IS NULL, 0 , field) FROM...` but ti doesn't change the behavior.

This is the sub-query isolated from the larger query:

```
strSQL = "SELECT SUM(IIF(RCTPAY2.[Sum Paid] IS NULL ,0 , RCTPAY2.[Sum Paid])) FROM [Receivables$B10:K32] AS RCTPAY2 WHERE RCTPAY2.[Invoice Number]=500009 AND RCTPAY2.[Method]='Tax Deduct'"
```

How can I make this always return a valid number (0 if no records or the SUM of field if there are records)?

This is the provider I'm using:

```
strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
```

**EDIT**: As per JNevill's request, I'm copying here the complete SQL query. Look for `HDR.[Total NIS]-(SELECT SUM`:

```sql
SELECT 'C100'+'000000000'+'024227357' + '320' + 
       FORMAT(HDR.[Invoice Number],'00000000000000000000') + 
       IIF(ISNULL(HDR.[Print DateTime]),'            ', 
           FORMAT(HDR.[Print DateTime],'YYYYMMDDHHMM')), 
           LEFT(TRIM(HDR.[Customer Name])+'                                                  ',50),  
       IIF(ISNULL(CST.[Bill To: Address1]), '                                                  ',  
           LEFT(TRIM(CST.[Bill To: Address1])+'                                                  ',50)),  
       IIF(ISNULL(CST.[Bill To: Address4]), '          ',  
           LEFT(TRIM(CST.[Bill To: Address4])+'          ',10)),
       IIF(ISNULL(CST.[Bill To: Address2]), 
           '                              ',  
           LEFT(TRIM(CST.[Bill To: Address2])+'                              ',30)),  
       IIF(ISNULL(CST.[Bill To: Address3]), '        ',  
           LEFT(TRIM(CST.[Bill To: Address3])+'        ',8)), 
       IIF(ISNULL(CNTRY.[Country]), 
           '                              ',  
           LEFT(TRIM(CNTRY.[Country])+'                              ',30)),
       IIF(ISNULL(CST.[Bill To: Address5]), '  ',  CST.[Bill To: Address5]), 
       IIF(ISNULL(CST.[Phone]), '               ',  
           LEFT(TRIM(CST.[Phone])+'               ',15)) ,  
       IIF(ISNULL(CST.[Company ID]), '000000000',  
           FORMAT(CST.[Company ID],'000000000')) + 
           (SELECT FORMAT(RCTPAY.[Date],'YYYYMMDD') 
            FROM [ùåøåú ú÷áåìéí$B10:K32] AS RCTPAY 
            WHERE RCTPAY.[Invoice Number]=HDR.[Invoice Number] 
              AND RCTPAY.[Line Number]=1) +  
                  IIF(True, 
                      IIF(HDR.[Currency]<>'ù÷ì çãù', 
                          FORMAT(100*HDR.[Total], IIF(HDR.[Total]<0, 
                                                      '00000000000000',
                                                      '+00000000000000')), 
                      '               '), '               ') +  
                  IIF (True, 
                       IIF(HDR.[Currency]<>'ù÷ì çãù', 
                           CUR.[IRS Code], '   '), 
                       '   ') + 
                  FORMAT(100*(HDR.[Subtotal] * HDR.[Exchange Rate]),
                  IIF(HDR.[Subtotal]<0,'00000000000000','+00000000000000')) +
                  IIF(ISNULL(HDR.[Discount%]),'               ', 
                      FORMAT(ABS(100*(HDR.[Subtotal] * HDR.[Discount%])),
                  IIF(HDR.[Subtotal]<0,'+000000000000000',
                      '-00000000000000'))) + 
                  FORMAT(100*(HDR.[Total In Currency] * HDR.[Exchange Rate]),
                         IIF(HDR.[Total In Currency]<0,
                             '00000000000000','+00000000000000')) + 
                  FORMAT(100*(HDR.[VAT] * HDR.[Exchange Rate]),
                         IIF(HDR.[VAT]<0,'00000000000000','+00000000000000')) + 
                  FORMAT(100*(HDR.[Total NIS]-
                         (SELECT SUM(RCTPAY2.[Sum Paid]) 
                          FROM [ùåøåú ú÷áåìéí$B10:K32] AS RCTPAY2 
                          WHERE RCTPAY2.[Invoice Number]=HDR.[Invoice Number] 
                            AND RCTPAY2.[Method]='ðéëåé îñ áî÷åø')),
                         IIF(HDR.[Total NIS]<0,
                             '00000000000000','+00000000000000')) + 
                  FORMAT(100*(SELECT SUM(RCTPAY3.[Sum Paid]) 
                              FROM [ùåøåú ú÷áåìéí$B10:K32] AS RCTPAY3 
                              WHERE RCTPAY3.[Invoice Number]=HDR.[Invoice Number] 
                                AND RCTPAY3.[Method]='ðéëåé îñ áî÷åø'),
                        '+00000000000') +  
                  FORMAT(HDR.[Customer Number],'000000000000000') +
                         IIF(ISNULL(HDR.[Source Invoice]), '          ', 
                             RIGHT('          ' + 
                             FORMAT(HDR.[Source Invoice],'##########'), 10)) +  
                         IIF(HDR.[Status]='îáåèìú','1',' ') +  
                             FORMAT(HDR.[Date],'YYYYMMDD') + '       ', 
                                   '         ',  FORMAT(HDR.[Invoice Number],
                                                        '0000000') + '             ' 

FROM ((([çùáåðéåú å÷áìåú$B12:AB55] as HDR 
LEFT JOIN [ì÷åçåú$B12:X20] as CST 
       ON HDR.[Customer Number] = CST.[Customer Number]) 
LEFT JOIN [èáìàåú$ET12:EU254] as CNTRY 
       ON CST.[Bill To: Address5] = CNTRY.[Code]) 
LEFT JOIN [èáìàåú$K10:O25] as CUR 
       ON HDR.[Currency] = CUR.[Currency]) 
WHERE HDR.[Date]>=43101 
  AND HDR.[Date]<=43465 
  AND HDR.[Status]<>'îîúéðä' 
  AND HDR.[Invoice Type]='çùáåðéú îñ/÷áìä'
```

Comment: Can you share the portion of actual SQL where you are adding the three. I believe your `iif` should reside there (unless this subquery is coming in through an `INNER JOIN`). I guess maybe if we could see the whole query as solving this in the subquery alone would require some oddball workaround with either a funky WHERE and an equally funky CASE or an ugly UNION.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(RCTPAY2.[Sum Paid] IS NULL ,0 , RCTPAY2.[Sum Paid]))
FROM [Receivables$B10:K32] AS RCTPAY2
WHERE RCTPAY2.[Invoice Number] = 500009 AND RCTPAY2.[Method] = 'Tax Deduct';
```

You are thinking:  "Gosh, this should never return `NULL`, because I check for it in the `IIF()`".  But you are missing something:  What if there are no rows?  That is the problem you are having.

So, instead of `IIF()` *before* the `SUM()` do the comparison *after* the `SUM()`.  Also, use `NZ()` rather than `IIF()`.  So:

```
SELECT NZ(SUM(RCTPAY2.[Sum Paid]), 0)
FROM [Receivables$B10:K32] AS RCTPAY2
WHERE RCTPAY2.[Invoice Number] = 500009 AND RCTPAY2.[Method] = 'Tax Deduct';
```

`SUM()` ignores `NULL` values anyway, so there is no need to turn them into zeroes.

If `NZ()` doesn't work, then try the ANSI standard `COALESCE()` function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(RCTPAY2.[Sum Paid]), 0)
FROM [Receivables$B10:K32] AS RCTPAY2
WHERE RCTPAY2.[Invoice Number] = 500009 AND RCTPAY2.[Method] = 'Tax Deduct';
```

I would only recommend `IIF()` or `IFNULL()` (and `NZ()`) out of desperation -- these are bespoke functions specific to a database.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Unfortunately, NZ is not recognized as a valid SQL function. I can only try a combination of IIF and ISNULL - but that construct fails on IIF missing () error.

Comment: @MorSagmon . . . `NZ()` is definitely an MS Access function (https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php).

Comment: yes, I know, and I expected it to work in Excel VBA as well - but it does not work with ADO

Comment: coalesce is also not supported. I can only try to use IIF with ISNULL, but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me eventually was an IIF that checks if the COUNT of the records under the same criteria is greater than zero, and then I apply the SUM command. Something like:

```
3 + IIF((SELECT(COUNT(*) FROM some-table WHERE some-criteria)=0,0, (SELECT SUM(field) FROM some-table WHERE some-criteria)
```